# Using a UIPickerView and changing what a button does

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uipickerview

Here is the code. I am trying to make the button do different things whenever something in a UIPickerView is selected.

```
 -(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    switch(Striped Bass)
    //Striped Bass
    {
            - (IBAction)calculateButtonPressed:(id)sender {
                NSLog(@"Calculate Pressed");

                float girth = [[self.girthTextField text] floatValue];
                float length = [[self.lengthTextField text] floatValue];

                NSLog(@"girth: %f length: %f", girth, length);

                float weight = girth * girth * length / 800;
                NSLog(@"Weight: %f", weight);

                NSString *weightText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", weight];

                self.weightTextField.text = weightText;
            }


    }
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken this code will give you a parse error.

Comment: @Ares Can you please help me fix this error

Comment: Why couldn't you update your previous question? There was no reason to post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear at all but I will give it a shot anyways.
I think you are confused about two things:

1. What a protocol is
2. How to make a call to a protocol.

One you press a button you (potentially) call an IBAction. 
When you select a row in a pickerView you trigger an event, that gets picked by the delegate, and do something with it.

So, in your code you are defining a method inside another one. This is not possible. the IBAction needs to be defined outside the definition of `didSelectRow`. If you really need to run that action then you need to call it manually. So your code should look more like this:

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
        {
            switch(Striped Bass)
            //Striped Bass

            [self calculateButtonPressed:pickerView];
        }

- (IBAction)calculateButtonPressed:(id)sender {
        NSLog(@"Calculate Pressed");

       float girth = [[self.girthTextField text] floatValue];
       float length = [[self.lengthTextField text] floatValue];

       NSLog(@"girth: %f length: %f", girth, length);

       float weight = girth * girth * length / 800;
       NSLog(@"Weight: %f", weight);

       NSString *weightText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", weight];

       self.weightTextField.text = weightText;
}
```

Now, what doesn't make sense to me is that you are not using at all the selected row in your method to do something based on the selected pickerView.

1. A protocol is the list of methods your object responds to.
2. When you want to call them you do [myObject nameOfMethod];

Anyhow, hope that helps.

Comment: I am trying to make a fish weigher type app where you have the length and the girth and it calculates the weight. Some species have different equations than others so Im trying to change that equation.

Comment: look at the comment above by me

Comment: So, why are you then getting your values from a textField as opposed to the selected row in the pickerView?

Comment: Because I need those values to find the weight. I am trying to make an app exactly like FishCalcLite by Scott Kehrberg on the AppStore. I am just doing it for fun. The app is small and free. I you could download it and look it would be helpful.

Comment: look above at the comment i just posted